# Gitlab pipeline failed - These dependencies were not found

Tags: vue.js, webpack, gitlab, vue-component, gitlab-ci

I had trouble running build in gitlab CI/CD - the .md import were not found.
I raw-loader to load the .md file in vue component.

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 3 errors2:48:13 PM
These dependencies were not found:
* @views/pages/support/content/http.md in ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_modules/thread-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/@vue/cli-plugin-babel/node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/router/views/pages/support/detail.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
* @views/pages/support/content/rest.md in ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_modules/thread-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/@vue/cli-plugin-babel/node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/router/views/pages/support/detail.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
* @views/pages/support/content/smpp.md in ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_modules/thread-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/@vue/cli-plugin-babel/node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/router/views/pages/support/detail.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
To install them, you can run: npm install --save @views/pages/support/content/http.md @views/pages/support/content/rest.md @views/pages/support/content/smpp.md
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Everything is working well when running local on my notebook pc. Bye the way, I'm using docker and vue-enterprise boilerplate. Anybody please kind advice?

Here is the pacakge.json

```
{
  "name": "PlasGateSMSGateway",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "dev:e2e": "cross-env VUE_APP_TEST=e2e vue-cli-service test:e2e --mode=development",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build --modern",
    "build:ci": "yarn build --report",
    "lint:eslint": "eslint --fix",
    "lint:stylelint": "stylelint --fix",
    "lint:markdownlint": "markdownlint",
    "lint:prettier": "prettier --write --loglevel warn",
    "lint:all:eslint": "yarn lint:eslint --ext .js,.vue .",
    "lint:all:stylelint": "yarn lint:stylelint \"src/**/*.{vue,scss}\"",
    "lint:all:markdownlint": "yarn lint:markdownlint \"docs/*.md\" \"*.md\"",
    "lint:all:prettier": "yarn lint:prettier \"**/*.{js,json,css,scss,vue,html,md}\"",
    "lint": "run-s lint:all:*",
    "test:unit": "cross-env VUE_APP_TEST=unit vue-cli-service test:unit",
    "test:unit:file": "yarn test:unit --bail --findRelatedTests",
    "test:unit:watch": "yarn test:unit --watch --notify --notifyMode change",
    "test:unit:ci": "yarn test:unit --coverage --ci",
    "test:e2e": "cross-env VUE_APP_TEST=e2e vue-cli-service test:e2e --headless",
    "test": "run-s test:unit test:e2e",
    "test:ci": "run-s test:unit:ci test:e2e",
    "new": "hygen new",
    "docs": "vuepress dev"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fullcalendar/bootstrap": "^4.3.0",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^4.3.1",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^4.3.0",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^4.3.0",
    "@fullcalendar/list": "^4.3.0",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^4.3.0",
    "@fullcalendar/vue": "^4.3.1",
    "animate.css": "^3.7.2",
    "apexcharts": "^3.8.5",
    "axios": "0.18.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.0.3",
    "feather-icons": "^4.24.1",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "lodash": "4.17.11",
    "metismenujs": "^1.1.0",
    "raw-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "v-click-outside": "^2.1.3",
    "v-mask": "^2.0.2",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-apexcharts": "^1.5.0",
    "vue-axios": "^2.1.5",
    "vue-feather": "^1.0.0",
    "vue-flatpickr-component": "^8.1.3",
    "vue-form-wizard": "^0.8.4",
    "vue-loading-overlay": "^3.3.2",
    "vue-markdown": "^2.2.4",
    "vue-meta": "1.6.0",
    "vue-multiselect": "^2.1.6",
    "vue-perfect-scrollbar": "^0.2.0",
    "vue-recaptcha": "^1.3.0",
    "vue-router": "3.0.6",
    "vue-scrollto": "^2.17.1",
    "vue-toastr": "^2.1.2",
    "vue2-dropzone": "^3.6.0",
    "vue2-editor": "^2.10.2",
    "vuedraggable": "^2.23.2",
    "vuelidate": "^0.7.4",
    "vuex": "3.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "3.7.x",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-e2e-cypress": "3.7.x",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "3.7.x",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "3.7.x",
    "@vue/cli-service": "3.7.x",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "4.0.x",
    "@vue/eslint-config-standard": "4.0.x",
    "@vue/test-utils": "1.0.0-beta.29",
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-eslint": "10.0.x",
    "babel-jest": "23.6.x",
    "cross-env": "5.2.x",
    "eslint": "5.16.x",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "vuejs/eslint-plugin-vue#edd5f14",
    "express": "4.16.x",
    "hygen": "2.1.2",
    "imagemin-lint-staged": "0.4.x",
    "lint-staged": "8.1.x",
    "markdownlint-cli": "0.15.x",
    "npm-run-all": "4.1.x",
    "sass": "1.19.x",
    "sass-loader": "7.1.x",
    "stylelint": "10.0.x",
    "stylelint-config-css-modules": "1.4.x",
    "stylelint-config-prettier": "5.0.x",
    "stylelint-config-recess-order": "2.0.x",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "18.3.x",
    "stylelint-scss": "3.6.x",
    "vue-template-compiler": "2.6.10",
    "vuepress": "0.14.x"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=10.13.3",
    "yarn": ">=1.0.0"
  }
}
```

Here is the vue.config.js

```
const appConfig = require('./src/app.config')

/** @type import('@vue/cli-service').ProjectOptions */
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.md$/i,
          loader: "raw-loader"
        }
      ]
    },
    // We provide the app's title in Webpack's name field, so that
    // it can be accessed in index.html to inject the correct title.
    name: appConfig.title,
    // Set up all the aliases we use in our app.
    resolve: {
      alias: require('./aliases.config').webpack,
    },
    performance: {
      // Only enable performance hints for production builds,
      // outside of tests.
      hints:
        process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' &&
        !process.env.VUE_APP_TEST &&
        'warning',
    },
  },
  css: {
    // Enable CSS source maps.
    sourceMap: true,
  },
  devServer: {
    disableHostCheck: true,
    host: "0.0.0.0"
  }
}
```

Here is the vue component

```
<script>
import appConfig from '@src/app.config'
import Layout from '@layouts/main'
import PageHeader from '@components/page-header'
import VueMarkdown from 'vue-markdown'
import restContent from '@views/pages/support/content/rest.md'
import httpContent from '@views/pages/support/content/http.md'
import smppContent from '@views/pages/support/content/smpp.md'
/**
 * Starter component
 */
export default {
  name: 'Support',
  page: {
    title: 'Support',
    meta: [{ name: 'description', content: appConfig.description }],
  },
  components: {
    Layout,
    PageHeader,
    VueMarkdown,
  },
  props: {
    data: {
      type: Object,
      required: false,
      default: () => ({
        name: 'rest',
        title: 'REST',
      }),
    },
  },

  data() {
    return {
      title: 'Support',
      items: [
        {
          text: 'Home',
          href: '/',
        },
        {
          text: 'Support',
          active: true,
        },
      ],
      cards: [
        {
          name: 'rest',
          title: 'REST',
          description: 'Whatever the api',
        },
        {
          name: 'http',
          title: 'HTTP',
          description: 'Whatever the api',
        },
        {
          name: 'smpp',
          title: 'SMPP',
          description: 'Whatever the api',
        },
      ],
    }
  },
  computed: {
    markdownContent() {
      let content = restContent
      if (this.data.name !== 'rest')
        content = this.data.name === 'http' ? httpContent : smppContent
      return content
    },
  },
  created() {
    if (this.data.hasOwnProperty('name')) {
      delete this.items[1].active
      this.items[1].href = '/support'
      this.items.push({ text: this.data.name, active: true })
    }
  },
}
</script>

<template>
  <Layout>
    <PageHeader :title="title" :items="items" />
    <div class="card col-9">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h3>
          <router-link
            tag="a"
            :to="{ name: 'Support' }"
            class="menu-icon align-middle text-dark"
            ><feather type="chevron-left"></feather
          ></router-link>
          {{ data.title }}
        </h3>
        <vue-markdown :source="markdownContent"></vue-markdown>
      </div>
    </div>
  </Layout>
</template>
```

Comment: Can you update your question to include the contents of your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file? Without it we can't help you find why it's not running in CI/CD.

Comment: @AdamMarshall, thanks for commented. by the found what wrong. I didn't delete *.md from .gitignore so there is no file over there. I'm freak stupid.